# keeping track of item number in a recursive call C#

Tags: c#, recursion

I was wondering if I want to keep track of the number of folders in a recursive method, how can I made it so the counter would not get reseted each time in the loop in below's code?

```
// how to keep track of the number of sourceFolder that has been processed?
public void recursiveMethod(SPFolder sourceFolder, SPFolder destinationFolder)
{
    int totalNumberOfFiles = sourceFolder.SubFolders.Count;

    foreach (SPFolder sourceSubFolder in sourceFolder.SubFolders)
    {
        if (true)
        {
            SPFolder destSubFolder = null;
            if (true)
            {
                destSubFolder = doSomething();
            }
            else
            {
                destSubFolder = doSomethingElse();
            }
        }
        recursiveMethod(sourceSubFolder, destSubFolder);
    }
}
```

The goal here is to display something like "processing folder ***15*** / 100" to the user.  I'm having trouble keeping the folder count without getting it resetted.  Assumption: the folders themselves dont have a unique ID.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This code allows you to show how many folders have been processed so far.  However it doesn't get the total amount of folders as is tricky: you can't know that until whole recursion has finished:

```
public void recursiveMethod(SPFolder sourceFolder, SPFolder destinationFolder)
{
    int folderIndex = 1;

    recursiveMethod(sourceFolder, destinationFolder, ref folderIndex);
}

public void recursiveMethod(SPFolder sourceFolder, SPFolder destinationFolder, ref folderIndex)
{
    int totalNumberOfFiles = sourceFolder.SubFolders.Count;

    foreach (SPFolder sourceSubFolder in sourceFolder.SubFolders)
    {
        // Display processed folder
        Console.WriteLine("Processing folder " + folderIndex);

        if (true)
        {
            SPFolder destSubFolder = null;

            if (true)
            {
                destSubFolder = doSomething();
            }
            else
            {
                destSubFolder = doSomethingElse();
            }
        }

        // Increase processed folder index
        folderIndex++;

        // Recursive call
        recursiveMethod(sourceSubFolder, destSubFolder, ref folderIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this is any better than passing in the current count and returning the potentially incremented count.

Answer (score 2):

Can you just pass the count variable as a parameter to the method?

Comment: Sure, and then have the method return the count. If that's not convenient, the count can be passed by reference.

Comment: Exactly. You can make that parameter optional with a default of 0 and be done with it.